# How to display a column when there is no data in it

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am working in Webi 4.2 and am new to Business Objects. I have a list of projects that each have tasks (in columns) and the dates (rows) that the tasks were completed on.  Not all projects have all the tasks hence the date for those tasks is blank.  But I need to display ALL the tasks (column) and leave the missing date as blank.  Could someone please help with this?

```
Project 1               
    task 1       task 2   task 3     task 4
    date         date     date       date
Project 2               
    task 1       task 2   -------   task 4
    date         date     blank     date
Project 3               
    task 1       -----    task 3    task 4
    date         blank    date      date
```

so in the above example, even when the task 3 does not exist for Project 2, i need to display 'task 3'

any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there something that would give you all possible tasks for a project?

Comment: No Issac, that's the problem, if the task does not exist for a project, there is nothing that is related to it because it isn't there for that particular project.

Comment: What is the data source for your report (e.g. Universe, Free-hand SQL, or something else)?

Comment: it's a Universe

Answer (score 0):

Create a cross table (i.e. crosstab) with **Project** as your vertical axis and **Task** as your horizontal axis. Then create a variable defined as...

```
=[Task Completion Date]
```

with the qualification designated as "Measure". Drag it into the field of your crosstab to set it as the body axis.

Comment: this worked.. thank you so much.. really appreciate it!